Prompt For Reboot If Required After Feature Install In PowerShell
I know this is something obvious, but I need another set of eyes...  I'm running PowerShell 5.1 on Windows Server 2022.  This is what I have:

    If($HTTPActive -ne 'True'){
        Add-WindowsFeature NET-WCF-HTTP-Activation45 -OutVariable RestartNeeded
        If($RestartNeeded.RestartNeeded -eq "Yes"){
            Write-Host "Restart required to complete installation of HTTP Activation feature"
            Write-Host "Please run the Installer again after the reboot"
            Pause
            Exit
        }
        
    }

If I run Add-WindowsFeature NET-WCF-HTTP-Activation45 the RestartNeeded value is "No," but every time I run this it tells me the the restart is needed.  If I run $ResartNeeded.RestartNeeded I get a value of "No."  What am I doing wrong?
Edit:  If I run $RestartNeeded.RestartNeeded.GetType() I get
IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType                                                                                                      
-------- -------- ----                                     --------                                                                                                      
True     True     RestartState                             System.Enum  ```

Edit Two:  I'm stupid...  I had this in the script twice and there may or may not have been conflicting data.  Once I got rid of the second time around, it worked.

Could you do $RestartNeeded.RestartNeeded.GetType() and 'Yes' -in $RestartNeeded.RestartNeeded ? That might give a hint as to why it is entering that condition

@SantiagoSquarzon I added the results from the first part.  I'm not sure what you're asking me to do in the second part.

@SantiagoSquarzon I'm stupid...  I had this in the script twice and there may or may not have been conflicting data.  Once I got rid of the second time around, it worked.

Got it, then the issue was caused by a typo
